# Sorting by hash values inside an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash, rubygems

Im trying to return a list of values inside of of an array of hashes from lowest to highest. I am using the google_drive gem to pull numbers from a google spreadsheet, displaying football information:

Here is where I'm at:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google_drive'

session = GoogleDrive.login("EMAIL", "PASS")




v_qb_w1 =  session.spreadsheet_by_key("xxxxxxxx").worksheets[0]

@quarterbacks = [ 

                { name: v_qb_w1[2, 1], projection: v_qb_w1[2, 2], salary: v_qb_w1[2, 3], dpp: v_qb_w1[2, 4], ppd: v_qb_w1[2, 5] },
                { name: v_qb_w1[3, 1], projection: v_qb_w1[3, 2], salary: v_qb_w1[3, 3], dpp: v_qb_w1[3, 4], ppd: v_qb_w1[3, 5] }, 
                { name: v_qb_w1[4, 1], projection: v_qb_w1[4, 2], salary: v_qb_w1[4, 3], dpp: v_qb_w1[4, 4], ppd: v_qb_w1[4, 5] }
                                      ]

puts "Value:"
@quarterbacks.sort_by do |key, value| 
 dpp = []
 dpp << key[:dpp].to_f.to_s
 puts dpp.flatten.sort.reverse
end
```

That last block was just one of my attempts to try and sort the :dpp key value from lowest to highest. Nothing fails, it just does not change anything. I've tried the grouby_by method and just have no luck arranging my key values

SOLUTION:

```
@quarterbacks.sort_by! { |qb| qb[:dpp] }
@quarterbacks.each { |qb| puts qb[:dpp] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) *returns* the sorted list, it doesn't sort it in place. That means that just:

```
@quarterbacks.sort_by { ... }
```

doesn't do anything useful as you're throwing away the sorted results. You'd need to add an assignment or use [`sort_by!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21):

```
@quarterbacks = @quarterbacks.sort_by { ... }
# or
@quarterbacks.sort_by! { ... }
```

Then you have understand how the `sort_by` block works. `sort_by` sorts using the block's return value, it is more or less like this:

```
array.map  { |e| [ sort_by_block_value[e], e ] }
     .sort { |a, b| a.first <=> b.first }
     .map  { |e| e.last }
```

so your block needs to return something sensible rather than the `nil` that `puts` returns:

```
@quarterbacks.sort_by! { |q| q[:dpp] }
```

Comment: so i had tried the bang method before, even though your explanation above helped a lot, it still returns an unordered list of values: 413, 516, 435, 410, 540, etc. Is there some sort of comparison inside the block I need to add? Right now I have this: @quarterbacks.sort_by!{|qb| puts qb[:dpp].to_f if qb[:dpp].to_f > 0 }

Comment: (1) Get rid of the `puts`, your block returns `nil` all the time because it is a call to `puts`. (2) Why is there a conditional in your block? Maybe it would help if you supplied sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@quarterbacks.sort_by!{|qb| qb[:dpp]}
```

You are trying to sort an `Array`. Right now you passing a `Hash`(k) and `nil`(v) because each quarterback is stored as a `Hash` so there is no `key => value` association in the `Array`. Also puts will return `nil` so you are telling it to sort `nil` against `nil` repetitively.

The code above will sort the `Array` of `Hash`es by the `:dpp` attribute of each `Hash` which seems like what you are asking for. The `!` in this case means it will alter the receiver altering the `@quarterbacks` instance variable to be sorted in place.